# Integrity constraint violated when deleting in grails

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I have the following domain classes

```
class User{
    static hasMany = [servers: Server]

    static mapping = {
        servers cascade: 'all-delete-orphan'
    }
}

class Server{
    int sid
}
```

When I delete a server, I get

> integrity constraint(XXXXXX.XXXXXXXXX) violated - child record found

How can I add `CASCADE ON DELETE` constraint to the foreign key in grails.

Comment: not sure, if this is the solution, but you have to do `static belongsTo = User` in the Server class, because otherwise the Server could be referenced by other Users and so could not be easily deleted. Another hint: if the server class just holds an int, then you could remove the class and use GORMs Feature to map [Basic Collection Types](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#basicCollectionTypes) like so: `static hasMany = [servers: Integer]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined a unidirectional relation between `User` and `Server`. And since the `Server` does not know its related `User` you need to do something like this:

```
def user = User.get(123L)

def server = user.servers.find { it.sid == 321 }

if (server) {
  user.removeFromServers(server) 
  user.save()
  server.delete()
}
```